# how to change the column data type, so the date is not missup?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a column with varchar(50) data type, but it stores date in this format `1/1/2000`.
I changed the data type to date using:

```
 alter table test_table modify date date;
```

but this changed the data values from `1/1/2000` to `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`.

I want to change the data type to date but the data should not get messed up like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE test_table  SET column=STR_TO_DATE(column,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Just use this and change the format to match what you have,can`t tell what is the day or month.
It will modify your column to date type,no need to recreate another column.

[The parameters](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/STRTODATEstrformat.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Step 1 - add a new column of datatype date.

Step 2 - use str_to_date() to update your new column.  This allows you to specify the format you are using.

Step 3 - drop the old column

Step 4 - rename the new column